# Comparing two ArrayLists of Objects

Tags: java, arraylist, unique

I have class named Student.
Also I have two array lists for Students A and Students B.

Students A could be: Maria, Alex, Lora, Vlad, Lauren, Catherine.

Students B is some students from A: Maria, Alex

Students A has the proper id and names stored.
But Students B has only prepared names and hardcoded id stored.

I separated these two lists and now want do the following:

if Maria form Array A has student id : 2427

Maria from Array B should receive the same student id.

Can you please help me to do that.

```
 //array lists of students a and b
public void common(){

     ArrayList<ArrayList<Student>> lists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Student>>();
     lists.add(a);
     lists.add(b);

     System.out.println(getCommonElements(lists));
     for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
         aa = lists.get(0);
         bb = lists.get(1);

     }
     System.out.println(aa);
     System.out.println(bb);
}


public static <T> Set<T> getCommonElements(Collection<? extends Collection<T>> collections) {

    Set<T> common = new LinkedHashSet<T>();
    if (!collections.isEmpty()) {
       Iterator<? extends Collection<T>> iterator = collections.iterator();
       common.addAll(iterator.next());
       while (iterator.hasNext()) {
          common.retainAll(iterator.next());
       }
    }
    return common;
}
```

Thank you in advance!
the question is rarely why this do not work?

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < b.size(); j++) {

      if(a.get(i).getName().equals(b.get(j).getName())){
                //does not go there at all
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: It sounds a little bit like you mainly dumped your homework assignment and the "template" code that your teachers expect you to fill. You see, we help with specific questions, not with "can you help me do that."

Comment: Are you trying to fill the ids from A to B to their corresponding names?

Comment: Yes. The problem is: I have already all the proper id for A. Now I need to take these id with corresponding names and set them to B ArrayList.

Comment: It is not an assignment. It is my practicing which is not related to college.

Answer (score 0):

Your iteration is not doing what you meant it to do. You are comparing elements at index 'i' in both arrays over and over, instead of elements in A at index 'i' and elements in B at index 'j'.

If you print out the name of each student that you comparing it should be clear to you.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I edited my post. I actually was comparing i and j. So it does not want to work, and have no idea why...